# Serverless async function error

Tags: node.js, async-await, serverless

I'm using serverless to run lambda functions.

Facing issue while tring to execute `sls invoke local --function myFunction`

```
exports.myFunction = async (event) => {
                         ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
```

Serverless config looks like this.

serverless.yaml

```
service: myService

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: eu-west-1

  environment:
    CUSTOM_ENV: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}


functions:
  myFunction:
    handler: index.myFunction
    events:
      - http: 
          cors: true
          path: /{proxy+}
          method: POST
plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-webpack
```

webpack.config.js

```
const slsw = require("serverless-webpack");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  target: "node",
  // Generate sourcemaps for proper error messages
  devtool: 'source-map',

  mode: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? "development" : "production",

  optimization: {
    // We no not want to minimize our code.
    minimize: false
  },
  performance: {
    // Turn off size warnings for entry points
    hints: false
  },


};
```

While running command `sls offline start`

everything seems to work fine until function route is hit.

Comment: I don't use Serverless, but the problem is that this Node version doesn't support async functions, so this `runtime: nodejs8.10` likely doesn't take effect, because they are supported in Node 8. Try to check what Node version is and log `process.version`

Answer (score 8):

`sls invoke local` **runs your code locally** by emulating the AWS Lambda environment. So, please ensure you have **node 8** and above installed in your dev machine for async await native support. Run `node --version` locally to check your node dev version.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are using ECMA script 8 on `estlintrc.js`.

Then it will be working properly.